# Mapbox React Native Ios

Tags: ios, react-native, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-ios, react-native-mapbox-gl

Just wondering if anyone is familiar with this error after installing '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps' into an Ios React Native app.

I've installed and updated the Podfile as instructed and am using the latest 8.02beta version of the npm library.

```
  Referenced from: /Users/benjaminwatts/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B9E73FD7-5C1C-4F93-AA54-D779ED8381AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FC4BA852-160C-4E9F-8601-3EBFAE4AAD26/hillbaggermobile.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/benjaminwatts/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19H524/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4.18D46
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/benjaminwatts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hillbaggermobile-epwacafnlywpvtfyuoeyrsvpsnos/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Libra
(lldb)
```

I suspect there is a missing native dependency for Mapbox which I am not aware of, but just wondering if anyone is familiar

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with latest version of Cocoapods and MapBoxGl. The way to tackle that issue is to downgrade your Cocoapods version and it will work. I can confirm that it works fine with Cocoapods version - 1.9.3